# How can I duplicate a cell value until the next filled cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that gets dumped out from a model I use.  Unfortunately, I have to take a lot of time by hand to fix these sheets every day.  However, it can be really easy to work with if this one change is made.

I attached a picture, the left is what it comes out of the model as, the right is what I would like it to be like in a new sheet.  The only problem I foresee is the number of values in the second column is different every time, so the labels in the first column aren't always in the same place.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.  [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqPvy.png)

Comment: What you want is absolutely doable. In order to use StackOverflow effectively, you'll have to show your VBA/macro code and what you've tried first. Explain what problems you're having and can't figure out. SO is not a code-writing service. My suggestion is to record a macro that uses all the steps you perform by hand, then go into the recorded macro to learn how VBA performs the same thing. Start making changes to the recorded macro to make it your own. Use google searches on SO and other Excel VBA sites to discover what works and what doesn't. Then come here to SO and post specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the first cell by hand and then just autofill this easy formula:

`F3=IF(F3<>"";F3;F2)`